# When to cast in swift

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop, casting

So this is probably a super simple question, but I have looked and cannot find the answer. 
Let's say I have made a class and I fill an NSMutableArray with instances of this class and that is it.  I want to use a for in loop to loop through. What is the easiest way to cast so I don't have to everytime I want to call the current instance in the loop?

Here it is shown:

```
    for m in objects {
      m.randomVar = "hello"
    }
```

where m is my custom object that has a randomVar as a String and objects is an array of custom objects.

Of course the code above will not execute because xcode assumes m is an [AnyObject?].  Where and how would be the best was to get m in its own class.  Let's assume we are changing more than one variable so casting everytime would not be optimal.

Sorry if I am unclear. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Avoid the problem.

   Don't use NSArray/NSMutableArray — just use `let`/`var` variables of pure Swift arrays, such as `[MyClass]`.

   Or, if your array is coming from Objective-C, in Xcode 7+ you can use the `NSArray<MyClass *> *` syntax to expose it to Swift as `[MyClass]` rather than `[AnyObject]`.
2. Cast the array.

   Use `objects as! [MyClass]` (**unsafe**) if you are absolutely sure it contains instances of `MyClass`.
3. Cast the variable.

   ```
   for m in objects {
       if let m = m as? MyClass { ...
       // or
       let myobj = m as! MyClass // unsafe
   ```

   or in Swift 2 (Xcode 7)

   ```
   for case let m as MyClass in objects {
       // this is executed only for objects which are instances of MyClass,
       // ignoring other objects in the array.
   }
   ```